# unable to extract the value of <img alt> in python

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to extract the brand name from the site http://www.snapdeal.com/product/aoc-e2060-swn-20-inch/622813?pos=0;85  from the below img tag:

```
      <img src="http://i1.sdlcdn.com/img/brand/logo/2012-08-01-02-31-15-AOC.jpg" alt="Aoc" width="75" height="45">
```

i.e, I want to extract "Aoc". I have tried this:

```
   hxs.select('//*[@id="wrapper"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/ul/li[1]/img/@alt').extract()).strip()
```

But I'm getting the null value. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ scrapy shell
<SNIP>
In [1]: fetch('http://www.snapdeal.com/product/aoc-e2060-swn-20-inch/622813?pos=0;85')
2013-10-16 00:37:08+0000 [default] INFO: Spider opened
2013-10-16 00:37:08+0000 [default] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.snapdeal.com/product/aoc-e2060-swn-20-inch/622813?pos=0;85> (referer: None)
<SNIP>
In [2]: hxs.select('//a[contains(@class, "brandName")]/img/@alt').extract()[0]
Out[2]: u'Aoc'
```

It's best to always get as "close" to your target as possible using XPath. All those div[1]/div[3]/span[1] nonsense is as brittle as it comes and very likely to break when the page changes.

There was nothing wrong with you using `"img/@alt"` and `.extract()` to get the alt attribute. Your overall path to the img node was wrong, is all.

Answer (score -1):

is this what you want ?

```
import re,requests
url=requests.get(" http://www.snapdeal.com/product/aoc-e2060-swn-20-inch/622813?pos=0;85")
re.findall(r'\<img src=.* alt="(.*)" width',url.text)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Got it , but this does extract AOC which is what he wants right ?

Comment: Extracting info from arbitrary HTML with pure regex is unreliable, so this is only good for a one-time job.